# Array of objects - modyfing object's fields C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I've got such a problem. I'm a beginner in C#. 
I have an object array (various classes) and in one place of application I want to modify fields like an age or name. Construction

```
static Object[] prac = new Object[10];
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    prac[0].age = 21;
}
```

shouts an error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'age' and no extension method 'age' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

I thought that will be similiar to a Java code, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: I don't think this code works in Java also, probably you mean javascript ( which is dynamic language) you need to cast from Object to the class you need...

Comment: Trying not to sound condescending, but I think you need to go take a tutorial in c#

Comment: Ow, I made a mistake. It's a `Person[] prac = new Person[10]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your member to the class type that contains the age. I'll just assume that your class name is `Person` and that is has a `age` member :

```
static Object[] prac = new Object[10];
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ((Person)prac[0]).age = 21;
}
```

Important to note are the brackets : `(Person)prac[0]` is the cast part, you cast the `Object` `prac[0]` to a `Person` object. The outer brackets `((Person)prac[0])` are there so that the code is taken as a `Person` object, instead of a regular `Object`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! My array type should be `Person` at all... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to cast the object to the type you're intending to work with.

If you work with type `object`, it has only a limited amount of properties and methods. To use property `age`, you first need to cast it to the corresponding type that has that property. For instance something like this:

```
static Object[] prac = new Object[10];
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SpecificType myObject = prac[0] as SpecificType; // returns null if not successful
    if (myObject != null)
        myObject.age = 21;
}
```

HOWEVER, I'm not convinced you're doing the right thing here. I'd personally avoid type `object` unless absolutely there would be no other way of doing it (and that is very rare in my code). C# is a strongly-type language and by using `object` you're prone to errors all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` doesn't have property `age`.
All `Object`'s properties and methods [are stated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's an array of *objects* and as the error message suggests, *'object' does not contain a definition for 'age'*

You need to declare your array with the type that has `age` field or property.And the you can modify it whatever you want. For example:

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an array of your class instead of `Object` which is the base type of all classes.

```
static MyClass[] prac = new MyClass[10];
```

or you have to cast it:

```
MyClass mc = (MyClass) prac[0];
mc.age = 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

Object is the base class for all classes in .Net.

Just cast the required value to the required typed class. Or Create a list with the right type instead of object.